# What is the maximum theoretical (and practical) limit to an engines Elo?

Tags: engines, software, programming, elo

If I'm not wrong, Chess #1 is at 2800 something, (Magnus) And the #1 Engine is Stockfish, with something of 3200-ish.
What I'm asking that is there any **theoretical limit** to the elo?

---

yes, I know, Elo is a measure of how good you are, **RELATIVE** to others. But is there any limit where the complexity of chess *breaks down*? Like some *point of singularity* where any ELO above it is no different from it?
(Eg. If 4000 is the singularity point, an ELO of 4500 won't be different from a rating of 5500)

---

And Finally, is there any practical limit? Because of how depth searches go, each extra depth increases the time and resources required exponentially. Assuming that we **don't** have an *infinite* computer with infinite resources and time, what is a good practical limit?

Comment: The short answer is, we don't know. It's hard to speculate about something that plays chess so well that no human can comprehend its games. Though Stockfish should almost certainly be rated higher than 3200.
On a side note, this probably also depends on the time control, in blitz a perfect player should score better against e.g. Stockfish, than in long time control play.

Comment: https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/5251/what-would-be-the-elo-rating-of-a-computer-which-plays-all-optimal-moves